# Seamless Android native (c++) and java debugging

Tags: android, debugging

I'm fairly new to Android development, but I'm looking for a seamless Android c++ and java debugging environment.

My initial research indicates that NVidia may be the only toolset that provides this functionality (https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-debug-manager-android-ndk) through Visual Studio.

Less seamlessly, VisualGDB and Eclipse may be used together (http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/codebug/) by using VisualGDB to debug c++ and Eclipse to debug java.

I've also read that Eclipse has the ability to debug c++ and java, but they cannot be done at the same time.

WinGDB is supposed to have the ability to debug c++ and java, but again not at the same time (http://www.wingdb.com/docs/pages/wga_dbgjava.htm).

Finally, IntellJ IDEA may be able to do both with a c++ plugins, but I have no idea if debugging both java and c++ is available.

Anyone try these various solutions?  If so how well did they work out?  Can you provide pros and cons to any particular solution?

Comment: I ended up using NVidia's NSight toolset which has been most excellent... https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition